# Possible to create a field type, that is the size of a single bit?

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I would like to create a field type that is only the size of a single bit in Dynamo AWS.

I created a field of type 'Binary' - and its value is '0000' (4 bits).

However when I read this value and get the sizeof it - it shows me that the size taken up is actually 8 (bytes) - which is huge.

The code below shows the return block I use to get the 'Binary' value of the AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue

```
(AWSDynamoDBAttributeValue *value)
{
  NSLog(@"i'm here %@, %lu", value.B, sizeof(value.B));
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

The `sizeof` operation returns the size of an object/type in bytes. If the smallest value is 1 then your minimum is 8 bits. I don't know for certain about C, but C++ guarantees that a `char`, which is the smallest possible type, contains at least 8 bits. Chances are that a basic standard like that will hold for both languages.

If you're looking to optimise the usage of bits in a variable then you might want to look into [bitmasking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_%28computing%29).

Comment: Thanks for the info Guy. Originally I was going to do a 'bit masking' operation. Basically a 64-bit integer 'on' or 'off' for 64 different user preferences. Then I realized 'wait a minute' if I could just have the field itself be a single 'bit' in the first place, then I could just lazily download a bit and not deal with bitmasking. There is the bitset STD http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/ - it just looks like the 'binary' AWS datatype doesnt support single bits http://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-dynamodb-support-for-binary-data/ though hopefully soon?

Comment: I don't know of any plans to introduce single bit types, so if I were you I'd manage the current situation. Anyway, the transfer of a single byte is never going to make a huge impact, even if you scale it way up.

Answer (score 0):

`.B` is a Binary data type, which is a Blob. In Objective-C, it's mapped to `NSData`, and `sizeof` is printing out the size of the pointer. Amazon DynamoDB recently introduced `BOOL` data type; however, it's not supported in the AWS Mobile SDK for iOS yet at this moment.

Comment: Does this mean that the field entry on the server only really takes up one 'bit' - and its just the NSData pointer that is taking up 8 bytes? If this is the case - this would be great for sparing on storage capacity. Many thanks.